# Losing decimals when using Oracle SDO_POINT in a view

Tags: oracle, spatial, oracle-spatial

We have a table containing coordinates, among other things. We used to store these in two number fields (x and y), but we've now replaced this with an SDO_GEOMETRY field. For backwards compatibility, we have created a view (with the same name as the table used to have), where we do:

create or replace view meas_pnt as
select ..., m.position.SDO_POINT.X x_coordinate, m.position.SDO_POINT.Y y_coordinate
from meas_pnt_tab m;

This works for both reading and writing, but when writing decimal numbers to the view, the decimals are lost. I can't figure out why. Can anybody help? The following illustrates the problem:

update meas_pnt_tab m set m.position.SDO_POINT.x = 2.3 where meas_key=1;
select m.position.SDO_POINT.X from meas_pnt_tab m where meas_key=1;
->  x is 2.3. Good!

update meas_pnt set x_coordinate = 2.3 where meas_key=1;
select m.position.SDO_POINT.X from meas_pnt_tab m where meas_key=1;
->  x is 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not reproduce your error. This is what I get:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE meas_pnt_tab (position sdo_point_type, meas_key NUMBER);

Table created
SQL> INSERT INTO meas_pnt_tab (position, meas_key) 
  2  VALUES (sdo_point_type(2.3,0,0), 1);

1 row inserted
SQL> SELECT m.position.X FROM meas_pnt_tab m WHERE meas_key=1;

POSITION.X
----------
       2,3
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW meas_pnt AS
  2  SELECT m.position.X x_coordinate,
  3         m.position.Y y_coordinate,
  4         m.meas_key
  5    FROM meas_pnt_tab m;

View created
SQL> UPDATE meas_pnt SET x_coordinate = 2.4 WHERE meas_key=1;

1 row updated
SQL> SELECT m.position.X FROM meas_pnt_tab m WHERE meas_key=1;

POSITION.X
----------
       2,4
```

Can you post your CREATE statements ?

Comment: Thank you, Vincent. I tried your statements and they actually work for me too. I'll have to investigate what we're doing differently.

Comment: I thought the transformation was done entirely by the view itself, but we had an "instead of update" trigger on the view that did some things. And it used integer variables internally. That's why the decimals got truncated. But thanks, until you answered I thought there was something odd going on with the SDO_POINT datatype.